# Should I use a callable/callback with a anonymous function in PHP(WordPress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, callback, closures

I've been using wordpress for a long time.

In wordpress, there are many cases which we may use callbacks, for example:

```
add_action('wp_init', 'action_on_init');

function action_on_init() {
    echo "Hello world!";
}
```

The above style is the most common style in *WordPress*.

But I think adding such a function name to a global context is however a bit dirty.

So I turned to write in an alternative way:

```
add_action('wp_init', function() {
    echo "Hello world!";
});
```

This style is a bit like javascript does. And it prevents namespace pollution.

But in fact I rarely saw any other people code like this, what's the point *NOT* using this? Or can I feel free to code in this way?

Comment: I think it's a personal choice. Although if you have a function that you can call in several places, it's more practical to have a defined function, that you can just put in the `add_action()`, instead of copying the whole code block in a new hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous function was introduced in PHP 5.3.0 and a lot of sites are still running in older version that is why not many people use it. And you're not able to remove the action with `remove_action` if you use anonymous function.